Why using SSL_peek returns duplicated data?
I made the following code to find the amount of bytes I need to read in order to reach the end of a given delimiter, by using SSL_peek.
int TcpClient::PeekEndOfDelimiter(const std::vector<unsigned char>& delimiter, int max_size) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> peek_buf(max_size);
    int total_bytes_peeked = 0;

    while (total_bytes_peeked < max_size) {
        int bytes_peeked = -1;
        
        bytes_peeked = SSL_peek(ssl, peek_buf.data() + total_bytes_peeked, max_size - total_bytes_peeked);
            
        if (bytes_peeked <= 0) 
            return -1;   
        
        total_bytes_peeked += bytes_peeked;

        auto found = std::search(peek_buf.begin(), peek_buf.begin() + total_bytes_peeked,delimiter.begin(), delimiter.end());

        if (found != peek_buf.begin() + total_bytes_peeked) 
            return found - peek_buf.begin() + delimiter.size();
    }

    return -1;
} 

Now, I tried this code when reading an HTTP response, by first peeking the end of headers (\r\n\r\n) and it does fairly well on small HTTP responses, but when the response contains lots of headers, the function will not find the end of the delimiter. When debugging, I noticed that peek_buf contains duplicated data, thus, never reaching the end of headers no matter what max_size I pass to the function. Am I not understanding how SSL_peek really works? The entire response should be available to read, and even if it was not, I'm using a blocking context anyway so I really do not understand why this is happening. Thank you.

SSL_peek() returns whatever data is stored at the front of the SSL's data buffer, up to the max size you specify. The data is not removed from the buffer.  So, you are simply peeking the same data over and over, regardless of where you decide to store it in memory. The data is left in the SSL buffer for the next peek/read to see.
For what you are attempting, you really should not be peeking at all, just read normally.  Use SSL_read() to actually remove data from the SSL buffer.  Maintain your own buffer, where you read data from the SSL buffer into your buffer, and then search and extract data from your buffer as needed, saving unused data in your buffer for future use.
For example:
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;

void TcpClient::ReadSSLIntoBuffer() {
    unsigned char tmp[1024];
    int bytes_read = SSL_read(ssl, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    if (bytes_read <= 0)
        throw ...;
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), tmp, tmp + bytes_read);
}

std:vector<std::string> TcpClient::ReadHeaders() {
    const char* delimiter = "\r\n\r\n";

    auto start = buffer.begin(), found;
    while ((found = std::search(start, buffer.end(), delimiter, delimiter + 4)) == buffer.end()) {
        size_t prev_size = buffer.size();
        ReadSSLIntoBuffer();
        start = buffer.begin() +
            (prev_size > 3)
                ? (prev_size - 3)
                : 0;
    }

    std:string data(buffer.begin(), found);
    buffer.erase(buffer.begin(), found + 4);

    std::vector<std::string> headers;
    // TODO: split data up into headers...
    return headers;
} 

void TcpClient::ReadBytes(void *data, size_t size_wanted) {
    while (buffer.size() < size_wanted)
        ReadSSLIntoBuffer();
    auto start = buffer.begin();
    std::copy_n(start, size_wanted, static_cast<unsigned char*>(data));
    buffer.erase(start, start + size_wanted);
}

Alternatively:
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;

void TcpClient::ReadSSLIntoBuffer() {
    unsigned char tmp[1024];
    int bytes_read = SSL_read(ssl, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    if (bytes_read <= 0)
        throw ...;
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), tmp, tmp + bytes_read);
}

std::string TcpClient::ReadLine() {
    const char* delimiter = "\n";

    auto start = buffer.begin(), found;
    while ((found = std::search(start, buffer.end(), delimiter, delimiter + 1)) == buffer.end()) {
        size_t prev_size = buffer.size();
        ReadSSLIntoBuffer();
        start = buffer.begin() + prev_size;
    }

    auto stop = found;
    if ((stop > buffer.begin()) && (*(stop-1) == '\r')
        --stop;

    std:string line(buffer.begin(), stop);
    buffer.erase(buffer.begin(), found + 1);

    return line;
}

std:vector<std::string> TcpClient::ReadHeaders() {
    std::vector<std::string> headers;
    std::string line;
    while ((line = ReadLine()) != "")
        headers.push_back(line);
    return headers;
} 

void TcpClient::ReadBytes(void *data, size_t size_wanted) {
    while (buffer.size() < size_wanted)
        ReadSSLIntoBuffer();
    auto start = buffer.begin();
    std::copy_n(start, size_wanted, static_cast<unsigned char*>(data));
    buffer.erase(start, start + size_wanted);
}

